# javascript basic syntax

Tags: javascript

could you tell me how to pass variables using javascript? I receive two args (tid,uid), I then need to concatenate them into variables (turl, turl2) so that they become "http://www.site.com/t/t.php?testid=5" and "http://www.site.com/t/t.php?testid=5&uid=12". Window.open needs to open these two variables (turl, turl2) but it is loading the var names not their values.

```
function open_win(tid,uid) {
var turl = "http://www.site.com/t/t.php?testid="+tid;
var turl2 = 'http://www.site.com/t/i.php?testid= +tid+ &uid=+uid +';
window.open('+ turl + ', '');
window.open('+ turl2 +', '');
}
```

Comment: You are forgetting to end your quote in the string literal.  You did it right for `turl`.

Comment: "[language] basic syntax" ... why don't you start reading a [nice tutorial on Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide)?

Comment: sorry all I am on a tight deadline to read. my apologies.

Answer (score 3):

Building strings 101

```
function open_win(tid,uid) {
    var turl = "http://www.site.com/t/t.php?testid="+ encodeURIComponent(tid);
    var turl2 = 'http://www.site.com/t/i.php?testid=' + encodeURIComponent(tid) + '&uid=' + encodeURIComponent(uid);
    window.open(turl, '');
    window.open(turl2, '');
}
```

Comment: you are my hero. thanks.